# How to generate mixed source and assembly list in GO?

Tags: go

I know how to get assembly representation of Go program, but how to get mixed listing like this in Go?

```cpp
    0:helloworld.c  **** #include <stdio.h>
    1:helloworld.c  ****
    2:helloworld.c  **** int main()
    3:helloworld.c  **** {
    19                            .loc 1 4 0
    20                            .cfi_startproc
    21 0000 55                    pushq   %rbp
    22                    .LCFI0:
    23                            .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    24 0001 4889E5                movq    %rsp, %rbp
    25                            .cfi_offset 6, -16
    26                    .LCFI1:
    27                            .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    4:helloworld.c  ****   printf("Hello world!\n");
    28                            .loc 1 5 0
    29 0004 BF000000              movl    $.LC0, %edi
    29      00
    ...
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools that lay these side by side. But things like `go tool objdump` will have line numbers. Other tools such as https://godbolt.org/ will have multiple tabs and color highlighting. Beyond that, asking for software/library recommendations is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Pretend we built `o.exe` executable from Go sources using `go build -o o.exe`.

The following command prints mixed source+disassembly for `strconv.Atoi` function:

`gdb -batch  -ex "set disassembly-flavor intel" -ex "disassemble /s 'strconv.Atoi'" o.exe`